# CentOS: How to uninstall gerrit server from CentOS release 6.4

Tags: linux, centos6, gerrit

I installed a Gerrit Server on my *CentOS 6.4* which was running perfectly

I installed it using below command:

```
wget https://gerrit.googlecode.com/files/gerrit-2.7-rc1.war
java -jar gerrit-2.7-rc1.war init -d [directory where I installed it]
gerrit.sh start
Starting Gerrit Code Review:OK
```

Now I want to uninstall or remove it safely from my CentOS machine. I searched it a lot over internet but didn't find any suitable command for the same.

After lot of search I tried to remove installation directory using `rm` and `rmdir` command but some directories inside gerrit directory comes again automatically named as:

1) cache

2) db

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the process is still running. You could have stopped it beforehand:

```
gerrit.sh stop
```

Now that you've removed its directory (hence this script), you should kill this process yourself. For exemple

```
ps -ef | grep gerrit
kill -9 <gerrit_pid>
```